# Calling an opencv Mat from a dll to windows forms, image is glitchy

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, opencv, picturebox

I have an openCv based dll, that connects to a camera. I then call a `cv::mat` object into a C# application, and display the image as a Bitmap in a picturebox object.
This works, but the image occasionally 'glitches', showing flashes of lines, static and pops, every few seconds.

Is there a way I can check if the bitmap is valid before displaying it?
When i show the image in the dll, using `cv::imshow`, it looks fine.

The code I have is:

in the c++ dll:

```
__declspec(dllexport) uchar*  getArucoFrame(void)
{   

        cv::Mat OriginalImg = returnLeftFrame(); // calls the frame from where the camera thread stores it.
        cv::Mat tmp;
        cv::cvtColor(OriginalImg, tmp, CV_BGRA2BGR);
        //if I cv::imshow the Mat here, it looks good.
        return tmp.data;
}
```

in the C# side:

```
//on a button
 threadImageShow = new Thread(imageShow);
 threadImageShow.Start();

//show image frame in box
private void imageShow()
{
    while(true)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = getArucoFrame();
        if (pictureBoxFrame.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBoxFrame.Image.Dispose();

        }
        Bitmap a = new Bitmap(640, 360, 3 * 640, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, ptr);
        pictureBoxFrame.Image = a;
        Thread.Sleep(20);


    }


}
```

//the dll call

```
 [DllImport("Vector.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr getArucoFrame();
```

As the image looks good in the dll, and glitchy in the picturebox, i am having trouble debugging this. Any help much appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have here is that you pass pointer to data of temporary image `cv::Mat tmp;` into C#, but it gets freed on exit of `getArucoFrame(void)`, thus it is dangling pointer. It may work, but seems it sometimes gets overwritten by new data. An easiest, but not the most optimal fix would be declaring it static `static cv::Mat tmp;` so it gets freed on DLL unload.

Comment: Thank you! I have been tearing my hair out over this for days. VERY much appreciate your help.